How to copy a file from folder A in root site to a folder B in a subsite, using SharePoint 2013 Rest API
I tried all the different solutions. None seem to work. Is there an endpoint for this?
I'm trying this -
await fetch("https://farmurl.com/sites/rootsitename/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('/sites/rootsitename/sitefiles/test.html')/copyTo(strNewUrl = 'sites/rootsitename/subsitename/testfolder/test.html', bOverWrite = true)", {method: "POST", "headers": {
    "X-RequestDigest": $('#__REQUESTDIGEST').val(),
    "accept": "application/json",
    "content-type": "application/json",
},})

but i get this error. the folder exists though.
{
"odata.error": {
        "code": "-2130247142, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException",
        "message": {
            "lang": "en-US",
            "value": "Folder \"testfolder\" does not exist."
        }
    }
}


I guess there is / missing in the destination folder address. Please try below code, it should resolve your issue:
await fetch("https://farmurl.com/sites/rootsitename/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('/sites/rootsitename/sitefiles/test.html')/copyTo(strNewUrl = '/sites/rootsitename/subsitename/testfolder/test.html', bOverWrite = true)", {method: "POST", "headers": {
    "X-RequestDigest": $('#__REQUESTDIGEST').val(),
    "accept": "application/json",
    "content-type": "application/json",
},});

